# Save a JSON image in a server

Tags: json, image, rest, upload, jax-rs

I'm writing a RESTful web application where I need to provide the service of uploading images for a user. Currently, I have been able to upload an image from my current machine but I need to send it as JSON data over the web through the REST protocol.

In the server, there is a Java application running Jax-RS to manage the RESTful service. I was planning to save the JSON data that contains the image in the server and then provide a URL to the user for him to be able to locate it's image on the server.

Can someone provide some ideas on how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send the image in a JSON object, then the image should be [Base64 encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) it, or some [other form of encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1443158/2587435). Then on the server side you will need to unmarshal the JSON and then decode back the image. You can get some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27949340/2587435) on how that can be done.

Optionally, instead of doing all the converting inside the resource method (as in the example linked above), you could write a [custom MessageBodyReader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26985702/2587435), where you can do the unmarshalling and decoding there.

If you decide you don't want to work with JSON, you can go the normal route and use Multipart. Depending on the implementation of JAX-RS you are using, multipart support will be different. You can see some examples (all examples have links to the official documentation)

- [Jersey example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614403/2587435)
- [Resteasy example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27623162/2587435)
- [CXF example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28483262/2587435)

There are other implementations, but I don't have examples for those. You will need to search for the documentation if you're using an implementation other than listed above.