# spring jersey POST serialized bean

Tags: java, spring, jersey

Is there any way to get `POST` request body as serialized bean instead of raw `json` `string`?
for example:

```
    @POST
    @Path(ResourceEndpoints.POST_USER_REGISTER)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response register(@RequestBody UserObject user) {
    ...
```

Then I would not have to write json serializer boiler-plate code in each request.

Currently I have to do like this:

```
    @POST
    @Path(ResourceEndpoints.POST_USER_REGISTER)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response register(@RequestBody String userObjectJson) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        UserObject userObject = gson.fromJson(userObjectJson, UserObject.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* stick to Gson, you need to write a `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter` pair to handle deserialization/serialization. This is how the request stream is converted into our domain objects and domain objects serialized to the response stream.

You can find a good explanation about this subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26985702/2587435) and you can find a simple implementation [here at Integrating Gson into a JAX-RS based application](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/11/02/integrating-gson-into-a-jax-rs-based-application/). I will post the implementation at the bottom (in case the side ever goes down).

However you register all your other Jersey components, i.e. resource classes and providers, register this `GsonMessageBodyHandler` the same way. If you have package scanning enabled, the class should be automatically picked up from the `@Provider` annotation. In any case the `@RequestBody` annotation shouldn't be needed (I don't work much with Spring, but I would guess it's ignored either way).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public final class GsonMessageBodyHandler implements MessageBodyWriter<Object>,
    MessageBodyReader<Object> {

  private static final String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";

  private Gson gson;

  private Gson getGson() {
    if (gson == null) {
      final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
      gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    }
    return gson;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
      java.lang.annotation.Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public Object readFrom(Class<Object> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws Exception, ApplicationException {
    InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(entityStream, UTF_8);
    try {
      Type jsonType;
      if (type.equals(genericType)) {
        jsonType = type;
      } else {
        jsonType = genericType;
      }
      return getGson().fromJson(streamReader, jsonType);
    } finally {
      streamReader.close();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public long getSize(Object object, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return -1;
  }

  @Override
  public void writeTo(Object object, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(entityStream, UTF_8);
    try {
      Type jsonType;
      if (type.equals(genericType)) {
        jsonType = type;
      } else {
        jsonType = genericType;
      }
      getGson().toJson(object, jsonType, writer);
    } finally {
      writer.close();
    }
  }
}
```